# Array of text don't fade out until the last one is appended

Tags: arrays, text, processing

I want to make a group of array fade out until the last array in this group was appended. for example, I use append to create zoog[0], zoog[1], zoog[2], and I want these three objects not fadeout until zoog[2] is created and wait for a second, the same situation with zoog[3], zoog[4],zoog[5], these three objects don't fadeout until zoog[5] is created. But now what I can do is make each object fadeout as soon as it is created.

```
Zoog[]zoog = new Zoog[1];
float count=0;
int xpos =0;
int ypos =0;
String message="haha";
int ntextsize = 20;
int nopacity =200;
int thistime = 0;
int thiscount = 0;
//Zoog zoog;

void setup() {
  size(400, 400);
    xpos = int(random(width/2-200, width/2+40));
  ypos = int(random(height/2, height/2-40));
  zoog[0] = new Zoog(xpos,ypos,message,nopacity);
}

void draw(){
  background(255,255,255);

  for(int i=0; i<zoog.length; i++){
//    if(millis()-thistime>4000){
//     zoog[i].disappear(); 
//    }
    zoog[i].jiggle();
    zoog[i].display();


  }
}


void mousePressed(){
   count = count + 1;
 // int thiscount = 0;
  if(count%3 ==0){
    xpos=int(random(30, width-30));
    ypos=int(random(10, height-10));

  }
  else{
    ypos = ypos+50;
//   thiscount = thiscount +1;
//   thistime = millis();
//  }
  }


 nopacity = int(random(100,255));
// text(message, xpos, ypos);
 Zoog b = new Zoog(xpos,ypos,message,nopacity);
 zoog =(Zoog[]) append(zoog,b);

}
```

Zoog class

```
class Zoog {
  int x;
  int y;
  String thatmessage;

  int opaci =0;

  Zoog(int xpo, int ypo, String thismessage, int opa) {
    x = xpo;
    y = ypo;
    thatmessage = thismessage;

    opaci = opa;
  }

  void jiggle() {

    x = x+int(random(-2, 2));
    y = y+int(random(-2, 2));
  }

  void display() {

    fill(0, opaci);
    text(thatmessage, x, y);
    print("x position is "+ x);
    print("y position is "+y);
  }

  void disappear() {
    for (int j=0; j<255; j++) {
      opaci = opaci -j;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: seems like I need to setup another array

Comment: Should I use ArrayList rather than append?

Comment: The problem is I want zoog[0], zoog[1], zoog[2] fade together only when zoog[2] is created

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly you want to make 3 zoogs and then start fading those three out until they're gone. If this is correct there are a couple of ways I'd go about doing this.

First, I wouldn't use an array especially if you're dynamically updating the amount inside it. If you want to do that I'd use, [arraylists](http://processing.org/reference/ArrayList.html). [Here's](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) the javadocs reference. Basically you'd initialize an arraylist of Zoogs and put the zoog.add(new Zoog...) in the mousepressed. The good thing about arraylists is that they have a number of member functions that can help you manipulate them. For instance, you can check the size of the arraylist in your draw function instead of the time. Once you're above 3 start fading the first 3 out until they're dead (using a Zoog member function to say they're dead). You can check that "isDead" member function in your draw loop and remove the correct dead Zoog while in your for loop.

Here's a rough implementation, assuming you created an isDead function in your Zoog class that just returns whether the opacity is greater than 0:

```
void Draw()
{
   for (Zoog zoog : zoogs) //for each statement simplifying the code -       
                           //says for each Zoog in zoogs do
   {
      zoog.jiggle();
      zoog.display();
   }

   if(zoogs.size() >= 3) {    
      for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
         zoogs.get(i).disappear();
      }
   }

   if (zoogs.get(0).isDead() && zoogs.get(1).isDead() && zoogs.get(2).isDead()) {
             zoogs.remove(2);
             zoogs.remove(1);
             zoogs.remove(0); 
   }
}
```

This is by no means a perfect example but it shows how to remove 3 zoogs at a time by lessening their opacity and checking whether they are dead. If you're clicking a million times then it will take a while for each chain of three to die.